Utilize delegatecall to set values for struct fields
There are two smart contracts, A and B. They have identical slot numbers for their state variables. I need to assign some values to a struct in B by delegatecalling the fillDev() function of A. However, whenever I try to make this call by executing the setDev() function of B, this error is thrown:
code: -32000,
  data: {
    hash: null,
    programCounter: 1441,
    result: '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001344656c656761746563616c6c2066616c65642100000000000000000000000000',
    reason: 'Delegatecall faled!',
    message: 'revert'
  },
  reason: 'Delegatecall faled!',
  hijackedStack: 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Delegatecall faled! -- Reason given: Delegatecall faled!

The Solidity whole code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT`
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract A{

    struct developer{
        bytes name;
        bytes field;
        uint salary;
    }

    developer Dev;

    function fillDev(string calldata s,string calldata f,uint u) external{
        Dev.name=bytes(s);
        Dev.field=bytes(f);
        Dev.salary=u;
    }
}

contract B{

    struct programmer{
        bytes fullname;
        bytes track;
        uint wages;
    }

    programmer Prog;

    function setDev(address targetContract,string calldata f,string calldata t,uint w) external{

        (bool success,bytes memory returnData)=targetContract.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("fillDev(string,string,uint)",f,t,w));
        require(success,"Delegatecall faled!");

    }

    function getDev() external view returns(string memory,string memory,uint){
        return (string(Prog.fullname),string(Prog.track),Prog.wages);
    }

}

How can I assign some values to struct by delegatecalling?

A struct is a new object layout.
You defined two different structs in your two contracts. Also your two variables Prog and Dev are not named the same therefore creating conflicts. First you should have the same order of layout for variables but also the same names. The best solution would be to create a variable such as a mapping or an array that would hold structs in storage as such: mapping( address => Developer) public developers; or Developer[] public developers; Also it is critical when using delecatecall that both contract A and contract B have the **same variable order AND names

Both of the answers provided below are incorrect and doesn't provide the solution.
The reason for this error is because your encoding is wrong.
When we encode the function signature, we use full names of the data types, we don't say uint, instead it's uint256
So instead of abi.encodeWithSignature("fillDev(string,string,uint)", s, f, u) It should be             abi.encodeWithSignature("fillDev(string,string,uint256)", s, f, u).
I have tested this code. and it works as expected.
The answer by @torof also has misinformation. The variables do not necessarily have to be of the same name. The EVM doesn't care about names while delegating a call, it just fetches the slot assigned to that variable and updates the same slot in the caller contract.
EDIT: I agree that keeping variables' names the same improves the readability and reduces any chance of mistakes. It's a good practice.

By the way, even by doing this change the struct can't be copied directly, unless being unpacked and returned as separate values.

I just focused on the delegateCall failing. But it's working as expected though. The values are being set in the delegateCall, Why this line Prog = Programmer(fullname, track, wages); 

Oh, I think I'd also misunderstood it a bit. Nvm, I've deleted my answer.

It's cool, could've just edited it ser.

Yeah, but as you’ve already addressed it to the point, so I don’t think it’s right to duplicate the answers.

Very nice, that is the correct technical answer indeed

As, @Zartaj has mentioned, while calling encodeWithSignature, it won't recognise uint, rather it should be the complete name of the type i.e., uint256.
But, even after doing this change, your code would work fine as long as Dev (i.e., the instance of Developer struct of contract A) and Prog (i.e., the instance of Programmer struct of contract B) are at the same storage slot i.e., 1st slot in this case.
So, as soon as you define any storage variable either above Dev or Prog like:
uint256 public storageVariable;

Developer public Dev;

Or,
uint256 public storageVariable;

Programmer public Prog;

The delegatecall would behave incorrectly, as shown:

So, in order to make it working as expected, irrespective of the storage slots of Dev and Prog, what you can do is:

Return the values of Dev (i.e., the instance of Developer struct) from the fillDev function of contract A.

In setDev function of contract B, decode the returnData (of type bytes) that you're getting from delegatecall, and store the same in a tuple (having the exact sequence of types as what you're returning from the fillDev function).

Assign those tuple values to Prog (i.e., the instance of Programmer struct).


Here's the full code to achieve the same:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract A {
    struct Developer {
        bytes name;
        bytes field;
        uint256 salary;
    }

    Developer public Dev;

    function fillDev(
        string calldata s,
        string calldata f,
        uint256 u
    )
        external
        returns (
            bytes memory,
            bytes memory,
            uint256
        )
    {
        Dev.name = bytes(s);
        Dev.field = bytes(f);
        Dev.salary = u;
        return (Dev.name, Dev.field, Dev.salary);
    }
}

contract B {
    struct Programmer {
        bytes fullname;
        bytes track;
        uint256 wages;
    }

    Programmer Prog;

    function setDev(
        address targetContract,
        string calldata s,
        string calldata f,
        uint256 u
    ) external {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = targetContract.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("fillDev(string,string,uint256)", s, f, u)
        );
        (bytes memory fullname, bytes memory track, uint256 wages) = abi.decode(
            returnData,
            (bytes, bytes, uint256)
        );
        require(success, "Delegatecall failed!");
        Prog = Programmer(fullname, track, wages);
    }

    function getDev()
        external
        view
        returns (
            string memory,
            string memory,
            uint256
        )
    {
        return (string(Prog.fullname), string(Prog.track), Prog.wages);
    }
}

With this, the delegatecall would behave correctly irrespective of the storage slots of Dev and Prog, as shown:


wow same time huhh

Slightly before you .

Good work though, It's sad to see people giving generic answers instead of solving the error. (And even the generic answers contain misinformation  )

Yes, they just seem to be in a hurry to answer first...
